# XCUITestCases - Login test cases are getting failed if app move to home screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

As we usually have the following flow from application root view -

```
if isUserLoggedin {
    /// Move to home screen
    moveToHome()
} else {
    /// Move to login screen
    moveToLogin()
}
```

I have the ui test cases for the login screen and all the test cases are correctly working when application move to the login screen. But the test cases are getting failed if user already logged in and move to home screen. I know since the login screen will not get loaded in that case so the test cases are getting failed.
I am not able to find the solution how can I test both login and home screen with proper flow ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want the user to login for each test? Or are you happy with them being logged in and therefore want to proceed with the test case?

Comment: First test Login test case. then test home test case. So it will test both scenarios.

Comment: @Cintu check my question what I wanted to ask.